# Bat file that searchs files and copy to folder

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, cmd.exe, search

Is there a way to create a batch file that do the follow:

- search for files in C:\ with these words in their name: password and username   ex. facebookpassword.txt or twitterusername.docx
- search in files for password and username. ex. twitterusername in the file: "Hello.txt"
- Copy the found files in C:\Credentials

Comment: What have you attempted so far? What difficulties have you run into?

Comment: Yes, but please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: If you want to search the content of office docs you better switch to vbscript/jscript/PowerShell which could better automate this. Otherwise start with `Dir /B/S/A C:\*password* >"C:\Credentials\Files_with_password_in_name.txt"`

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you might need:

> search for files in C:\ with these words in their name: password and username ex. facebookpassword.txt or twitterusername.docx

```
dir /s /b *password*
```

> search in files for password and username. ex. twitterusername in the file: "Hello.txt"

```
 find "password" Hello.txt
```

> Copy the found files in C:\Credentials

```
 copy path_to_src  C:\Credentials
```

In total it would look like this:

```
for /f "delims=#" %%i in ('dir /s /b *password*') do ( 
 echo %%i
 find "password" %%i
 if %ERRORLEVEL%==0 (
  copy "%%i" C:\Credentials\
 )
)
```